# Browser gives access to root directory through "/"

Tags: network, web-browser, privacy

If I put a '/' on my browser I have full access of my root directory. I have tried the same thing on another computer and it didn't work. So, I'm trying not to be paranoid but this is too strange. I have tried to check open ports using:

`lsof -i -P | grep -i "listen"`

but each time I kill any of the ftp open ports processes it opens another. Is there any way I can fix this? I think I have a netcat running on my computer and just can't get rid of.

Also if I check the network using `netstat` it gives me some datagrams without any information, everything is with a `"*"` value.

Please help!

Comment: Post the output of `ps -aux`

Comment: Are you sure you aren't just using the built in capability of the software to browse the local file system, just like every local app can see the local file system (ala file > open)? What symptoms do you have to indicate this is anything different or extraordinary?

Comment: Which URL are you browsing exactly? A URL begins with some letters followed by the three punctuation characters `://` (e.g. `file:///` or `http://localhost/` or `ftp://localhost/`). With what browser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For many Linux browsers (I've tested Opera, Firefox, and Konqueror), this is normal: a bare `/` is an invalid URL (there's no protocol), and it gets interpreted as `file:///`: "display a directory listing of the root directory".  There's no security risk here: only you can display the contents of your computer's root directory using a [file:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) URL, you cannot display the root directory of any other computer, and browser security policies keep Javascript from accessing it.

The `file:///` URL (or its Windows equivalent, `file://c|/`) is often used in scareware scams: the scammer will display it in an iframe on their website and try to convince you that it represents some horrible security leak, which their software can patch.

Comment: Firefox doesn't even seem to allow `file:///` URLs to be displayed in an iframe. At least, I couldn't get it to work.